# xmpp tls response format

Tags: xmpp, ssl

I cannot seem to find what format should be included in the TLS response after I get the challenge. Where can I find that info?

Say I was doing it in PHP, should it look like:

```
$nonce = "somenoncevaluehere";
$qop = "auth";
$charset = "utf-8";
$algorithm = "md5-sess";
$server = "example.com";
$user = "bob";
$pass = "somepass";

$md5Response = "realm=$server,nonce=$nonce,qop=$qop,charset=$charset,algorithm=$algorithm,xmpp,$server,$user,$pass";
```

Comment: It is an XMPP response, not a TLS response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [cocoa version](http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/)

```
NSMutableString *buffer = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:100];
[buffer appendFormat:@"username=\"%@\",", username];
[buffer appendFormat:@"realm=\"%@\",", realm];
[buffer appendFormat:@"nonce=\"%@\",", nonce];
[buffer appendFormat:@"cnonce=\"%@\",", cnonce];
[buffer appendFormat:@"nc=00000001,"];
[buffer appendFormat:@"qop=auth,"];
[buffer appendFormat:@"digest-uri=\"%@\",", digestURI];
[buffer appendFormat:@"response=%@,", [self response]];
[buffer appendFormat:@"charset=utf-8"];

NSLog(@"decoded response: %@", buffer);

NSData *utf8data = [buffer dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

return [utf8data encodeBase64];
```

Comment: You'll want to read and understand RFC 2831 (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2831) to ensure you know what all of those options do, if you want to interoperate with others.